# What are the abandoned technologies in aviation industry

Tags: aviation-history

And technologies has come to end of to their life cycle  Especially technologies that developed for aviation. This could be a manufacturing technology or an engine rather than avionics or sensors.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest one that comes to mind for me is Cathode Ray Tube technology for cockpit displays.  Rockwell Collins (called something else now) has ceased production of CRT displays and users of Proline CRT Primary Flight Displays, Secondary Flight Displays and EICAS systems are in a scramble to replace the CRTs when they wear out.  There are a number of companies offering LCD units to upgrade CRT units under STC and this is happening across the airline industry.

Another one could be navaids like Non Directional Beacons that are starting to go the way of the A/N Range and the related receivers, and eventually other analog navigation equipment.

Mechanically, not that much.  Light aircraft are still built today with magnetos that use points and condensers like tractors from the 40s.  They are simple and work.  The business is very conservative, a vital self-preservation characteristic in such a life-or-death environment, and things that are simple, work, and are easy to fix and easy to diagnose, and let you know when they are degrading, are hard to replace.

Answer (score 2):

1. Venturi tubes to drive vacuum gyros.

   [image: Venturi tubes]

   One could say the vacuum drive as such is abandoned, but the current C172S still has it.
2. Corrugated skin.

   [image: Ju-52]

   <sup>Photo by Stefan Krause, from [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ju52_100831.jpg)</sup>

Of course, we need to exclude vintage and replica aircraft: one could probably find some flying with any technology.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking more navigation related - ADF, NDB, LORAN, VOR getting there.
Incandescent light bulbs going away, being replaced by LEDs.
Vacuum pumps & vacuum driven gyros going away too.

Comment: Bulbs etc. are still plentiful in older flying aircraft, and can't always be replaced with LEDs. But when it comes to navigation, one could mention astronavigation (with sextant etc.) or even 'land and ask locals where you are' (no joke, it was happening in the early days).